# When is an active record really inserted into the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have a server setup where a rails server is writting into the same database as an java enterprise server. We have an api for the enterprise server implemented on the rails server that will create a user. It looks like this:

```
    user = User.new
    user.name = "Test"
    user.save()
```

The problem we are facing now is that when the user create request returns the user id to the enterprise server it sometimes is not found by the enterprise server in the database.

When does ActiveRecord insert a new entity into the database? Is there a way to ensure that when save returns that the database insert statement was performed?

The rails version is 2.3.10

Comment: You would usually use AR callbacks for a case like this. They should fire after the save is complete. If that dosnt work for you you might have some DB issues. Does the record get created at all in the SQL server or does the Java app just try once and give up?

Comment: We run a few more tests and it seems that this is an issue with hibernate which we use on the enterprise server. Rails does write it correctly. But some caching in hibernate prevents the server from reading the newly created user. Thx Devin for your help.

Comment: Still, you want to use AR call backs. Dont just call save and then call your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for this. They let you perform an action after the save takes place.

Comment: It was not the correct solution for our problem but I think this answer might help others to solve similar issue so I will accept it.